# botframework - AdaptiveCards on slack?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Does anyone know if adaptive cards render correctly on slack channel? I have cards than I confirmed works on the Microsoft bot emulator and webchat, but only one line of text appears in slack.

Comment: Please post the .json for the card your showing.  (Adaptive Cards on Slack aren't 100% supported.  Button mapping works, and I believe most cards are down rendered to an image.)

Comment: Here is the JSON that works in Bot Emulator, WebChat, but not in Slack or Skype: https://jsonblob.com/cb2782b5-65a6-11e7-a38a-f96c851a0d43

Comment: More info: This json contains a base64 encoded image (barcode) is causing problems on Slack.

Answer (score 1):

AdaptiveCards are not supported on slack.  They have their own json layout called BlockKit.

Comment: Also block kit is not supported in Azure Bot Services. You need to use the slack-adapter.

Comment: @matt-cobb Is there an utility or package to convert the BlockKit layout to AdaptiveCards?

Comment: @ParagJadhav I don't know